# Format datetime column to ISO date-time in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to convert datetime column to ISO datetime format without any success.

The only correct result I managed to get is by doing this sql:

```
select TO_CHAR(getdate(), 'YYYY-MM-DD')||'T'||TO_CHAR(getdate(),'HH24:MI:SS')
```

but I'm sure there is a more adequate method to achieve this.

Just to make sure I'm clear enough, I'm trying to get this format:
2011-12-03T10:15:30

P.S.

I tried the trivial sql and it doesn't work ==>

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(getdate(), 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SS');
```

gives this result:

2017-02-19THH24:38:46

and of course I wanted it differently: 
2017-02-19T10:38:46

Answer (score 17, accepted):

OK, I managed to achieve this with the mix of ' and " ==>

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(getdate(), 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS');
```

gives the result of: 2017-02-19T16:00:40

EDIT:
I found a simpler solution:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(getdate(), 'YYYY-MM-DDThh24:MI:SS');
```

It appears that the upper HH made a problem. Once converted to hh it worked

Comment: Thanks, the 2nd solution is nicer IMO.

Comment: The second solution still works but beware it's not documented so it may break in the future.